# Authorization Header in ImageMapType Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-maps-api-3, authorization

I'm currently working with Google Maps Javascript API V3 in Angular.
I'm trying to retrieve some tiles from the server, but I can't seem to be able to authorize the requests.

The current implementation is very basic:

```
{
...
    const maxZoom = 17;
    const minZoom = 10;
    const imageMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
      minZoom,
      maxZoom,
      getTileUrl: this.getTileUrl,
      tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256)
    });

    this.map.overlayMapTypes.push(imageMapType);
...
}

private getTileUrl(tile, zoom) {
    return `https://somelink/${zoom}/${tile.x}/${tile.y}.png`;
}
```

But I've already ran into an issue - the server responds with a 401 message!

Upon closer look, it turns out that the requests in fact don't have any Authorization header specified. I think that the requests made by ImageMapType are not caught by Angulars interceptors, which attach the token in my app.

I've been looking at the google docs [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#CustomMapTypes), but I just can't find anything on how to add Authorization to the requests made by ImageMapType.

Comment: Yes, those requests made by the maps API aren't running through your angular http client. In my experience, when you load Google Maps, you specify your API key at that point. You pass it as a query string parameter when you're loading the maps API